# Console Based Calculation For Super Human Mind Training?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Thanks for giving me your valuable time,  I wanna create a Brain Calculation Package. Basically, I will generate random numbers and throw it to user and user will enter the result. This will test his accuracy and will make him more sharp.

But, I am pretty confused to use what sort of programming language. My aim is to make the user to calculate digits till 100 digits with time. Please throw some light on this.
What sort of algorithms and strategies can i use?

Are there any other programs available currently to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea what you're trying to do. But if I were drunk and wanted to spit out random numbers, I'd probably use [Python](http://www.python.org/).